# Why is the same function in python multiprocessing Pool so much slower?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For testing out multiprocessing I created the following code (so_stuff is just some task that takes a long time and a lot of CPU and then I try out running it in parallel):

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import math


def do_stuff(x):
    print(f'Start executing {x}')
    j = 0
    temp = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(50000000):
        j += math.sqrt(i)
    print(f'Running with {x} as argument took {time.perf_counter() - temp} seconds')

    return j


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(do_stuff(0))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.map(do_stuff, [1])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(do_stuff, [11, 22])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
    pool.map(do_stuff, [111, 222, 333])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(do_stuff, [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444])
    print('Try out with two processes but four arguments')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(do_stuff, [-11, -22, -33, -44])
```

Note that regardless of the input to `do_stuff` it should take the same amount of time. My CPU has four cores. I find it strange that the `do_stuff` function is sooo much slower (note that I did not measure the time to create processes etc., only the pure function execution time) when there are multiple instances running in parallel. Each process uses 25% of my CPU (as I can see in Task Manager), so this seems fine. Apart from that there is not much going on (I have some browser tabs open and I listen to music via internet, takes 5% to 10% of CPU). So how can you explain these results?

```
Start executing 0
Running with 0 as argument took 10.575453699999999 seconds
235702256859.7696
Start executing 1
Running with 1 as argument took 10.5839916 seconds
Start executing 11
Start executing 22
Running with 11 as argument took 13.2278068 seconds
Running with 22 as argument took 13.483765799999999 seconds
Start executing 111
Start executing 222
Start executing 333
Running with 222 as argument took 18.1229912 seconds
Running with 111 as argument took 18.2985854 seconds
Running with 333 as argument took 18.3475558 seconds
Start executing 1111
Start executing 2222
Start executing 3333
Start executing 4444
Running with 2222 as argument took 25.8355925 seconds
Running with 1111 as argument took 25.8631132 seconds
Running with 4444 as argument took 25.7908253 seconds
Running with 3333 as argument took 25.923264699999997 seconds
Try out with two processes but four arguments
Start executing -11
Start executing -22
Running with -11 as argument took 13.294244099999998 seconds
Start executing -33
Running with -22 as argument took 13.2954416 seconds
Start executing -44
Running with -33 as argument took 14.2386355 seconds
Running with -44 as argument took 14.2992687 seconds
```

Running four processes in parallel takes more or less the same time as twice two processes in parallel. Is that normal?

Comment: Could not reproduce on my end. Regardless, might just be a memory issue if you tested this on a low-end device. Instead of doing `j += math.sqrt(i)`, try doing just `math.sqrt(i)` and see if the relative difference is the same.

Comment: Also, if the cpu usage is close to 100%, then that might be what's causing the issue as well. You should aim for it to be somewhere between 90-95% so that it doesn't throttle itself.

Comment: You need to distinguish between *logical processors* vs. *physical cores*.  The number of logical processors is often twice the number of physical cores because of hyper-threading technology incorporated on select Intel Processors (Hyper Transport on AMD). I suspect you have only 2 physical cores and 4 *logical* processors. Depending on what your 4 processes (threads) are doing, your CPU chip may only be able to run in parallel 2 processes. This would appear to be your situation. See [this article](https://techgearoid.com/articles/difference-between-physical-cores-and-logical-processors/).

Comment: [`perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) is system-wide so you should compute the timings via [`process_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) instead.

Comment: Indeed, I found out that my CPU is a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz which has only two physical cores and four logical processors. So it seems that with processes like mine with a lot of computing having four logical processors does not help.

I rewrote this program with java and there you get more or less the same picture (except that everything is 50 times faster...)

To Charchit: Taking away the j+= did not change the picture a lot.